# how to join 4 table in linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

i'm starter in linq and EF. i Have 4 table

CurrencyUnit

```
CurrencyUnitID    CurrencyName
-------------------------------
1                    Dolar
2                    Pond
```

Request

```
RequestID    WayBillNo
--------------------------
1            10000
2            10001
```

CostType

```
CostTypeID      CostName
-------------------------------
1                 A
2                 B
```

RequestCost

```
RequestId    CostId     CurrencyUnitId     Amount   Remark
-----------------------------------------------------------
1              1              1            200
1              2              1            400
2              2              2            1000
```

i Want join this 4 table and get this result

result(A table)

```
RequestId  WayBillNo  CostId    CostName  CurrencyUnitId   CurrencyUnitName  Amount   Remark
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           10000        1        A          1                 Dollar       200       
1          10000        2         B          2                 Pond         400
2          10001        1         A          0                               0
2          10001        2         B          2                Pond          1000
```

i write this Query

```
  var items = (from rc in context.CLEARANCE_COST
                join c in context.COST_TYPES on rc.COST_ID equals c.COST_ID 
                join d in context.CLEARANCE_REQUEST on rc.REQUEST_ID equals d.REQUEST_ID
                join f in context.CURRENCY_UNITS on rc.CURRENCY_ID equals f.CURRENCY_ID 
                select new
                           {

                               rc.COST_AMOUNT,
                               c.COST_ID,
                               c.COST_NAME,
                               d.WAYBILL_NO,
                               f.CURRENCY_NAME
                           }).ToList();
```

but get this result(B table)

`RequestId  WayBillNo  CostId    CostName  CurrencyUnitId   CurrencyUnitName  Amount Remark`

---

```
1           10000        1        A          1                 Dollar       200       
1          10000        2         B          2                 Pond         400
2          10001        2         B          2                Pond          1000
```

Namely
if request hasn't cost show all cost for this request and set Amount value 0 , for example A table has 4 rows but B table has 3 rows in Table A for request 2 cost 1  set amount 0 but in table B not set, i Want set.

Comment: Do you want to perform an inner or outer join?

Comment: hi , check the query of answer............

Comment: what you want as result ? not getting you at all

Comment: hi check my EDITed anser might work for you....:)

Comment: @mohsen: the schema is not clear. Assuming Request is your "root" table. Request has a 0 to N relation with RequestCost, RequestCost has a 0 to N relation to CurrencyUnit and CostType? Or some of them are 1 to N (FK not nullable)?

Comment: @munissor:all relation are 1..n and all relation are not Null

Comment: @mohsen: but is possible to have a Request without requestcosts, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write this code

```
 var items = from c in context.COST_TYPES
                    join o in context.CLEARANCE_COST .Where(d=>d.REQUEST_ID==8) on c.COST_ID equals o.COST_ID into outer
                    from o in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                               {
                                   o.CLEARANCE_REQUEST.WAYBILL_NO,
                                   c.COST_NAME,
                                   o.CURRENCY_UNITS.CURRENCY_NAME,
                                   Amount=o==null?0:o.COST_AMOUNT
                               };
```

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT**

Try left outer join in linq like as below....

```
var query=
    from rc in RequestCost
    join c in CostType on rc.CostId    = c.CostTypeID into RCC
    from rcc in RCC.DefaultIfEmpty() 
    join r in Request on  rc.RequestID = r.RequestID  into RCR
    from rcr in RCR.DefaultIfEmpty()   
    join cu in CurrencyUnit 
    on rc.CurrencyUnitId  = cu.CurrencyUnitID into RCCU
    from rccu in RCCU..DefaultIfEmpty() 

    select new 
       { 
          RequestId = rc.RequestId,
          WayBillNo = rcr != null ? rcr.WayBillNo : "<No WayBillNo>",
          CostId = rc.CostId,
          CostName = rcc != null ? rcc.CostName : "<No CostName>",
          CurrencyUnitID= rc.CurrencyUnitID,
          CurrencyName = rccu != null ? rccu.CurrencyName: "<No CurrencyName>",
          Amount = rc.Amount != null ? rc.Amount : 0 ,
          Remark = rc.Remark != null ? rc.Remark : "<No Remark>",
       }
```

---

so the query for you for according to you table will be

```
var query=
    from rc in RequestCost
    join c in CostType on rc.CostId    = c.CostTypeID
    join r in Request on  rc.RequestID = r.RequestID    
    join cu in CurrencyUnit on rc.CurrencyUnitId  = cu.CurrencyUnitID 

    select new 
       { 
          rc.RequestId,
          r.WayBillNo,
          rc.CostId,
          c.CostName 
          rc.CurrencyUnitID,
          cu.CurrencyName,
          rc.Amount,
          rc.Remark                     
       }
```

Check the post for more detail : [SQL to LINQ ( Visual Representation )](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/12/sql-to-linq-visual-representation.html)

image shows how the joins work in linq 
[image]

Comment: @mohsen - you need to include your "context" object for each of the collection query given by me is the how you can achieve it replace each object collection with "context.youobject" collection

Answer (score 1):

In case of a left outer join (assuming that the FK in RequestCost can be null)

```
var query=
    from rc in RequestCost
    join c in CostType on rc.CostId equals c.CostTypeID into ctype
    join r in Request on  rc.RequestID equals r.RequestID into req
    join cu in CurrencyUnit on rc.CurrencyUnitId equals cu.CurrencyUnitID into unit

    select new 
       { 
          rc.RequestId,
          req.FirstOfDefault() != null ? req.FirstOfDefault().WayBillNo : null,
          rc.CostId,
          ctype.FirstOfDefault() != null ? ctype.FirstOfDefault().CostName : null,
          rc.CurrencyUnitID,
          ctype.FirstOfDefault() != null ? ctype.FirstOfDefault().CurrencyName : null,
          rc.Amount,
          rc.Remark                     
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code too

```
public class Request()
{
          public int RequestId    { get; set; }
          public RequestCost RequestCost { get; set; }
}

public class RequestCost ()
{
          public int RequestId    { get; set; }
          public CostType CostType { get; set; }
          public CurrencyUnit CurrencyUnit{ get; set; }
}

  var items = context.dbRequest.include("RequestCost")
                                   .include("RequestCost.CurrencyUnit")
                                  .include("RequestCost.CostType").ToList();
```